# sql: Scan error on column index 0, name "": unsupported Scan, storing driver.Value type int64 into type *main.SMSBlast?

Tags: sql-server, go, orm

I'm now try restful api, where column SequenceID not auto incerement because on purpose  ,my problem is with library gorm when I count like this countSequenceId := db.Debug().Table("SMSBlast2").Count(&smsblast1) , result is sql: Scan error on column index 0, name "": unsupported Scan, storing driver.Value type int64 into type *main.SMSBlast

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
    "github.com/jinzhu/gorm"
    _ "github.com/jinzhu/gorm/dialects/mssql"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "strconv"
    "time"
)

type SMSBlast struct {
    SequenceID   int `gorm:"primary_key";column:"SequenceID"`
    MobilePhone string `gorm:"column:MobilePhone"`
    Output  string  `gorm:"column:Output"`
    WillBeSentDate *time.Time `gorm:"column:WillBeSentDate"`
    SentDate *time.Time `gorm:"column:SentDate"`
    Status *string `gorm:"column:Status"`
    DtmUpd time.Time `gorm:"column:DtmUpd"`
}

func (SMSBlast) TableName() string {
    return "SMSBlast2"
}


func insertSMSBlast(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){
    fmt.Println("New Insert Created")
    db, err := gorm.Open("mssql", "sqlserver://sa:@localhost:1433?database=CONFINS")
    if err != nil{
        panic("failed to connect database")
    }
    defer db.Close()


    vars := mux.Vars(r)
    mobilephone := vars["mobilephone"]
    output := vars["output"]

    var(
        smsblast1 SMSBlast
    )
    countSequenceId := db.Debug().Raw("SELECT COUNT (*) FROM SMSBlast2").Scan(&smsblast1)
    fmt.Println(countSequenceId)
    msg, err :=  json.Marshal(countSequenceId)
    if err != nil{
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
    }



    sequenceid1,_ := strconv.Atoi(string(msg))
    fmt.Println("SequenceID : " , sequenceid1)

    smsblasts := SMSBlast{SequenceID: sequenceid1,MobilePhone: mobilephone,Output:output, DtmUpd: time.Now()}
    prindata := db.Create(&smsblasts)
    fmt.Println(prindata)
}


func handleRequests(){
    myRouter := mux.NewRouter().StrictSlash(true)
    myRouter.HandleFunc("/smsblaststest",allSMSBlasts).Methods("POST")
    myRouter.HandleFunc("/smsblaststestInsert/{mobilephone}/{output}", insertSMSBlast).Methods("POST")
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080",myRouter))

}

func main(){
    fmt.Println("SMSBLASTS ORM")
    handleRequests()
}
```

Comment: `Count()` expects value argument of type `int64` instead of `SMSBlast`. Try passing a int64 variable.

Comment: Count() calculates a number of records, so it needs an integer not a struct

Comment: @MadWombat  , I have try to change to my code with using db.raw , you can my see my code below I have change my code , but now I get [1 rows affected or returned ] , but after I fmt.Println(countSequenceId) print nil , how to display result count to golang ?

Comment: @hassansin I have change my code , How I dispay query gorm to string like  count = 10 ?

Comment: That was not your problem. Your problem is that no matter whether you use Gorm method Count() or raw SQL, the result is an integer, not SMSBlast. So you need to pass a reference to an integer, not a reference to a struct.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to assume that Gorm methods will return the result for you. That is not how it works. Gorm returns an error or a nil and you pass a reference to a variable where you want to store results. So to use Count() on something you would write something like

```
var count int
db.Model(&SMSBlast{}).Count(&count)
fmt.Printf("count: %d\n", count)
```

That said, if you just want to make sure that you get a new sequence ID every time, why don't you use auto-increment?

```
type SMSBlast struct {
    SequenceID   int `gorm:"primary_key";column:"SequenceID";"AUTO_INCREMENT"`
    ... 
}
```